# Draw cone hat with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, ellipse

[image]
How is the hat in the following picture drawn, everyone?
I want to draw a dashed line from the first intersection of the great ellipse with the cone's birth line to the second intersection. Instead I have to estimate the measurements to draw.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,line cap=round, >=stealth, font=\footnotesize]
    \def\a{1.5}
    \def\b{.6}
    \def\h{3.5}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\g{asin(\b/\h)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\xo{\a *cos(\g)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\yo{\b *sin(\g)}
    \draw[dashed] (\xo,\yo) coordinate (M) arc (\g:180-\g:{\a} and  {\b})  coordinate(N) (180:\a) (90:\h) coordinate(S) --(0:0);
    \draw (-\xo,\yo) arc (180-\g:360+\g:{\a} and {\b}) (M)--(S)--(N);
    \pgfmathsetmacro\aa{2*\a}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\bb{2*\b}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\gg{atan(\a/\h)}
%   \path[name path=SM] (S)--(M);
%   \path[name path=ellipseB] (0:\aa) arc (0:180:{\aa} and {\bb});
%   \path[name intersections={of=SM and ellipseB}] (intersection-1) coordinate(I) node{I};
%   \path (0:0) coordinate(O) node{O} (0:\aa) coordinate(C) ($(O)!(I)!(C)$) coordinate(H) node{H};
%   \draw let \p1=($(H)-(O)$), \p2=($(I)-(H)$) in (0:\aa) arc (0:atan(divide(veclen(\x2,\y2),veclen(\x1,\y1))):{\aa} and {\bb});
    \draw (0:\aa) arc (0:70:{\aa} and {\bb}) coordinate(P) (0:\aa) arc (0:-250:{\aa} and {\bb});
    \draw[dashed] (P) arc (70:110:{\aa} and {\bb});
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the `fillbetween` library that is provided by `pgfplots` (which loads `tikz`):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round, line cap=round, >=stealth, font=\footnotesize]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{1.5}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{.6}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\h}{3.5}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\g}{asin(\b/\h)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\xo}{\a*cos(\g)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\yo}{\b*sin(\g)}
    \draw[dashed] 
        (\xo,\yo) coordinate (M) 
        arc[start angle={\g}, end angle={180-\g}, x radius={\a}, y radius={\b}] coordinate (N) 
        (180:\a) 
        (90:\h) coordinate(S) -- (0:0);
    \draw[name path=SM] 
        (-\xo,\yo) 
        arc[start angle={180-\g}, end angle={360+\g}, x radius={\a}, y radius={\b}] 
        (M) -- (S) -- (N);
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\aa}{2*\a}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\bb}{2*\b}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\gg}{atan(\a/\h)}
    \path[name path=ellipseB] 
        (0:{\aa}) 
        arc[start angle={0}, end angle={180}, x radius={\aa}, y radius={\bb}];
    \draw[intersection segments={of=SM and ellipseB, sequence={R2}}, dashed];
    \draw[intersection segments={of=SM and ellipseB, sequence={R1 R3}}];
    \draw 
        (0:{\aa}) 
        arc[start angle={360}, end angle={180}, x radius={\aa}, y radius={\bb}];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative [Metapost](https://tug.org/metapost.html) approach using the ability to copy the current picture and clip it to a path.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    path brim, band, cone, apex;
    band = fullcircle scaled 10mm yscaled 1/2;
    brim = band scaled 3;
    apex = (40mm +-+ length point 0 of band) * up;
    numeric r; r = 1/8;  % allow a little perspective...
    cone = subpath (4-r, 8+r) of band -- apex -- cycle;

    draw band;
    draw brim;
    draw point 4 of band -- point 0 of brim;

    picture hidden; hidden = currentpicture;
    clip hidden to cone; unfill cone;
    draw hidden dashed evenly scaled 1/2 withcolor 3/4;

    draw cone;
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Compile this with `lualatex` to get a PDF that looks like this:

[image]

It does look rather odd being so tall, but I used the dimensions written on the OP picture.